# Circle to circle collision

Tags: java, graphics, collision-detection

I am trying to write a Java program to support off-lattice diffusion limited aggration simulation.  Basic code to simulate a moving particle is in place, until said particle hits a static center particle.  At that point I try to make sure the moving particle is just touching (tangeant to) the static one.  However, for unknown reasons, it sometimes fails (the first 2 of 8 particles intersects, the 6 others are fine).

Here is the code:

```
    boolean killed, collide;
    double xp, yp, dx, dy, theta, xpp, ypp, length;

    int xc = 200;
    int yc = 200;
    int killRadius = 200;
    int releaseRadius = 150;
    int partRadius = 14;
    int partDiam = 2 * partRadius;

    drawCircle(xc, yc, killRadius); // kill
    drawCircle(xc, yc, releaseRadius); // release
    drawCircle(xc, yc, partRadius); // center particle

    //while (true) {
        killed = false;
        collide = false;

        theta = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
        xp = xc + releaseRadius * Math.cos(theta);
        yp = yc + releaseRadius * Math.sin(theta);

        while (true) {

            theta = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
            length = partDiam;

            xpp = xp;
            ypp = yp;

            xp = xp + length * Math.cos(theta);
            yp = yp + length * Math.sin(theta);

            //drawCircle((int) xp, (int) yp, partRadius);

            // Should it be killed ? (maybe could use a box to fasten
            // computations...
            // Would switching the test for kill w test for collision
            // improve perf ?
            dx = xp - xc;
            dy = yp - yc;
            if ((dx * dx) + (dy * dy) > killRadius * killRadius) {
                killed = true;
                break;
            }

            // Does it collide with center? replace by any particle...
            dx = xp - xc;
            dy = yp - yc;
            if ((dx * dx) + (dy * dy) < (partDiam) * (partDiam)) {
                collide = true;
                break;
            }
        }
// Probably something is wrong here...
        if (collide) {
            // no absolute value because particles move at most by diameter
            double depthPenetration = partDiam
                    - Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));
            dx = xpp - xp;
            dy = ypp - yp;
            // shorten distance travelled by penetration length to ensure
            // that
            // particle is tangeant
            length = Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy)) - depthPenetration;
            xp = xpp + length * Math.cos(theta);
            yp = ypp + length * Math.sin(theta);
            drawCircle((int) xp, (int) yp, partRadius);
        }
    //}
```

Of course I checked many references before asking, but cannot find anything wrong with the code... Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Too much code for me to debug.  Let's start with - what output are you getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: If I were you, I would create a series of unit tests that test the calculations.

Comment: I have to admit Im still having a really hard time understanding what you are trying accomplish much less your question about what you are wanting fixed?  What are the problematic symptoms, what are you expecting, and what are you getting?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: There are zillions of variables, all declared upfront, non of them is declared final. That makes it pretty hard to reason about them. When is which variable changed, are they changed at all? When are the set, when read, will they be read again? Do they need to have such a big scope?

Answer (score 1):

I made some simple refactorings through your code, just to get a feeling what it does, what is happening.

Let me mention one thing at start: It's the revival of the sphaghetti-monster, isn't it? Do you like global variables? Long, superpotent *let's do it all right now and here* methoods?

If you introduce variables as late as possible, the reader of your code needn't search upwards, what this variable has been been before - if something is overridden, for example, if there is a ungood reuse.

If your variables don't change: Make them final. That simplifies reasoning about them. `final int killRadius = 200;` means, that get the type information, together with the value, and hopefully shortly before first usage, and that it will never get changed. Configuration only in source code. Probably not a too complicated candidate. In contrast to double dx - not initialized, because it get's initialized inside the loop,

```
static void foo () {

    final int xc = 200;
    final int yc = 200;
    final int killRadius = 200;
    final int releaseRadius = 150;
    final int partRadius = 14;

    drawCircle (xc, yc, killRadius); // kill
    drawCircle (xc, yc, releaseRadius); // release
    drawCircle (xc, yc, partRadius); // center particle

    //while (true) {
    boolean killed = false;
    boolean collide = false;

    double theta = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;     
    double xp = xc + releaseRadius * Math.cos (theta);
    double yp = yc + releaseRadius * Math.sin (theta);
    double dx, dy, xpp, ypp;

    while (true) {

        theta = Math.random () * Math.PI * 2;
        final int partDiam = 2 * partRadius;
        final double length = partDiam;

        xpp = xp;
        ypp = yp;

        xp += length * Math.cos (theta);
        yp += length * Math.sin (theta);

        dx = xp - xc;
        dy = yp - yc;
        if ((dx * dx) + (dy * dy) > killRadius * killRadius) {
            killed = true;
            break;
        }

        // Why again assign dx = xp -xc? Did any of these values change meanwhile? 
        // I don't think so.
        // dx = xp - xc;
        // dy = yp - yc;
        if ((dx * dx) + (dy * dy) < (partDiam) * (partDiam)) {
            collide = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (collide) {
        // no absolute value because particles move at most by diameter
        double depthPenetration = partDiam - Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));
        dx = xpp - xp;
        dy = ypp - yp;
        // shorten distance travelled by penetration length to ensure
        // that
        // particle is tangeant
        final double length = Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy)) - depthPenetration;
        xp = xpp + length * Math.cos (theta);
        yp = ypp + length * Math.sin (theta);
        drawCircle ((int) xp, (int) yp, partRadius);
    }
```

If you structure your code like this, you not only see, that some value like xc is 200 and never changed - in the head of the while loop you see that theta is not declared inside the loop, so either it is used later outside the loop, or it is sequentially modified inside the loop. To do an x += 4; you can't initialize x in ever loop passing.

In the end of the big while, you have two similar blocks:

```
    dx = xp - xc;
    dy = yp - yc;
    if ((dx * dx) + (dy * dy) (OP) a OP b) {
        c = true;
        break;
    }
```

but xp, xc and dx aren't changed meanwhile - nor the y-equivalents. Is this a mistake, or why do you assign them again?

Then, you can get rid of your endless while this way: Since both conditions terminate the while, put the conditions into the while - test, and call the second block (without repeating the assignment) only if the first wasn't entered - keyword to do so is `else`:

```
    while (!killed && !collide) {

        // ...

        dx = xp - xc;
        dy = yp - yc;
        if ((dx * dx) + (dy * dy) > killRadius * killRadius) {
            killed = true;
        }
        else if ((dx * dx) + (dy * dy) < (partDiam) * (partDiam)) {
            collide = true;
        }
    }
```

What does it help in finding the error? Not so much. If two circles are placed wrongly, and the rest fine, a screenshot would be fine, and values, which lead to bad circles, and values which are alright.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I can debug your code, but I wrote some java.awt.Shape based collision routines many years ago (over a decade ago) that may help... check out the ShapeUtils.java from this:

http://www.cs101.org/psets/breakout/solns/breakout-src.jar

One of the very likely problems you may have is that java circles are spline curves with 4 points, and thus if you check if all the points defining the circle are inside another shape, you will still miss the case where the spline curve bulges into the other shape, but none of the points are actually inside the object. My solution (which might not be good enough for your case was to remake shapes until the distance between the points along their respective edges was smaller than the largest acceptable error:

```
   /**
     * Convert any AWT shape into a shape with a specified precision.
     * The specified precision indicates the maximum tolerable distance
     * between knot points. If the shape is already precise enough then 
     * it is returned unmodified.
     *
     * @param aShape the shape to be converted if necessary.
     * @param precision the maximum tolerable distance between knot points.
     * @return A more precise version of the shape, or the same shape if
     *         the precision is already satisfied.
     */
    public static Shape getPreciseShape(Shape aShape, float precision) {
```

This precision along with the velocity of the simulated object, told me how often in the simulation I had to check for collisions (the max delta time)... fast moving simulated objects can zip right through solid objects in a single time interval if you don't scale the time interval to be less than the time it takes to travel your desired precision.

Basically in this way it became a direct trade off between calculation cost and precision of the result. In my case I just wanted the game to look good, and so I only needed to be so precise as to ensure that objects never overlapped by more than half a pixel or so.

**Edit:** Let me summarize my suggestion... in re-reading I realize I got lost in the details and never manage to point out the key concept... Java has lots of routines that work quite well for testing various implementations of Shape (including circles). My suggestion is use the java libraries as much as possible, and get results that you can verify are correct. Once you've got working code and methodology for checking that the code works, if you need more speed, start optimizing portions of it, preferably after profiling the running program (that produces correct results) to see what parts are limiting your performance.